# mysql display each day data for specified date range

Tags: mysql

**Query:**-Display `customername,total_return` in last 7 days,and `quantity_sold` to the customer for the last 7 days with
each day representing a column,as follows,i did till first 3 columns.

But i don't know how to display data for each particular day or date.

```
customername        total_retuns    total_sold   t_6 t_5 t_4 t_3 t_2 t_1 t
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
karan       |        80            |   200      |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
hemanth     |        90             |  300                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Select Query:**

```
select c.Name,sum(od.return_quantity) totalReturns,
       sum(od.quantity_sold) quantitySold from customer c

left join orders o on c.CustomerId=o.CustomerId

left join order_details od on o.OrderId=od.orderid

where o.OrderedDate between curdate()-6 and curdate()
      group by c.Name order by totalreturns;
```

Comment: Please share you db structure with some data for better understanding.

Comment: there are three tables 1]orders{orderid,date,customerid(foreignkey),relationshipmanager},2]order_details{odid,orderid(foreignkey),total_return,quantity_sold,price} 3]customer{customerid,name,city}.

Comment: i want to display total_return for each day..